# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) not sure what am i doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I'm trying to setup a javascript(Es6 +) project, i've setup Webpack with Babel, it seems to be converting my code to Es5 but for some reason Import statements are not working where as require works. Nothing fails during build time but while running the application it Prints this error, the bundled output seems to be slightly off

```
index.js:14 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
    at Object../src/index.js (soem.2a9b32189bc67cc82c15.js:1189)
    at __webpack_require__ (soem.2a9b32189bc67cc82c15.js:727)
    at fn (soem.2a9b32189bc67cc82c15.js:101)
    at Object.0 (soem.2a9b32189bc67cc82c15.js:1225)
    at __webpack_require__ (soem.2a9b32189bc67cc82c15.js:727)
    at soem.2a9b32189bc67cc82c15.js:794
    at soem.2a9b32189bc67cc82c15.js:797
```

bundeled output

```
__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
/* harmony import */ var _someModule_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ./someModule.js */ "./src/someModule.js");
/* harmony import */ var _styles_scss_main_scss__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ./styles/scss/main.scss */ "./src/styles/scss/main.scss");
/* harmony import */ var _styles_scss_main_scss__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(_styles_scss_main_scss__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__);
// const { dk } = require('./otherModule.js');


var tt = 'hdh';
var tk = {
  tt: 'hdhd',
  replace: '""'
};
dkk();
soObject(_someModule_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["dkk"])); /Object(_someModule_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["some"])nsole.log(`jdjdjdj ${tt} ${tk}`);//# sourceURL=[module]
```

there is an extra closing bracket after ["dkk"]

package.json

```
{
  "name": "sdk-v10-web",
  "version": "10.0.9",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config build-utils/webpack.config.js --env.env=dev --hot",
    "build": "npm version patch && webpack --config build-utils/webpack.config.js --env.env=prod",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.6.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^1.7.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.8.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.3.1",
    "style-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "webpack": "^4.39.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.7",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.8.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.2.1",
    "webpack-plugin-replace": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "last 10 version",
    "> 1%",
    "not ie < 8"
  ]
}
```

webpack.common.js

```
const path = require('path');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const ReplacePlugin = require('webpack-plugin-replace');
const fs = require("fs");

const REPLACEABLES = {
  PROMPT_TEMPLATE: ''//fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../src') + '/prompt-templates/master-template.html', "utf8"),
}

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(js)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              options: {
                presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
              }
            }
        },
        {
            test: [/.css$|.scss$/],
            use: [
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                // 'style-loader',
                'css-loader',
                'sass-loader',
                'postcss-loader'
            ]
        },
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js']
    // alias: {
    //   // Utilities: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/utilities/'),
    //   // Templates: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/templates/')
    // }
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html'
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: 'hansel.[contenthash].css'
    }),
    new ReplacePlugin({
      exclude: [
        /node_modules/,
        /build-utils/,
        /dist/,
      ],
      values: {
        '%%REPLACE%%': JSON.stringify(REPLACEABLES.PROMPT_TEMPLATE)
      }
    }),
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../', 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'soem.[hash].js'
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
    host: "localhost.soem.io",
    open: true,
    port: 8080,
    // https: true,
  },
};
```

webpack.dev.js

```
const { DefinePlugin } = require('webpack');
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  plugins: [
    new DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {    // console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV); in source code
        'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
      }
    }),
    new Dotenv({
      path: './.env.development',
    }),
  ],
};
```

webpack.prod.js

```
const { DefinePlugin } = require('webpack');
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  plugins: [
    new DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {  // console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV); in source code
        'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production'),
      }
    }),
    new Dotenv({
      path: './.env.production',
    }),
  ],
};
```

webpack.config.js

```
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');

const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = ({ env }) => {
  const envConfig = require(`./webpack.${env}.js`);

  return webpackMerge(commonConfig, envConfig);
};
```

someModule.js

```
export function some() {
    // function someMethod() {
    //     console.log('someMethod');
    // }
    console.log('fsf');
}

export function dkk() {
    // function otherMethod() {
    //     console.log('otherMethod')
    // }
    console.log('hshs');
    return 'tt';
}
// some();

// export default some;
```

index.js

```
// const { dk } = require('./otherModule.js');
import {some, dkk } from './someModule.js';
import './styles/scss/main.scss';

const tt = 'hdh';
const tk = {
    tt: 'hdhd',
    replace: '%%REPLACE%%',
}
dkk();
some();

console.log(`jdjdjdj ${tt} ${tk}`);
```

Comment: It's also missing the `co` before the ``nsole.log(`jd...``, looks like a weird error to have

Comment: Yes, this is super weird, @CertainPerformance do you know someone who can help out?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was `webpack-plugin-replace` plugin, this was for some reason breaking the output, used `string-replace-loader` instead to do the job